# Drupal deployment - blog content separation from node table

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have 3 environments : dev, staging and live .

I use drupal and all content pages need to be synchronized when I deploy from dev-> staging -> live . I use a python deployment script (migraine) to copy the drupal mysql tables I want to migrate .

My problem is that I don't want to migrate the blog articles from dev because I don't want to force the blog editors to publish their articles twice (on live and dev) so when I do the release I don't destroy any new blog posts.

The problem is that the blog posts are stored in the node mysql table . I need to deploy the node table every time for new pages improvements, etc. The node table holds all content from all pages on a drupal website.

How can I sort this out without having to customize the drupal blog module ?

Bare in mind that I can't customize the deployment script just to deploy the nodes that don't have the type='blog' because the ids are sequecial and the blog articles would be erased when on dev I add new pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

- If the Node ID is the only thing that is stopping you from just excluding blog, you could use the [UUID module](http://drupal.org/project/uuid) to give each node a universally unique identifier.
- Rather than relying on the python script to migrate your content, have you looked into any of the Drupal modules that are written for this purpose? There's the [Deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) and the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) among others.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am going to look into this. This should help me a lot !